# Merge Sort in Python Bug

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I'm trying to implement a merge sort in Python. I completed a merge sort lesson on Khan Academy where they had me implement it in JavaScript, but I wanted to try and implement it in Python.

Lesson: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms#merge-sort

Here is my code:

```
from math import floor

def merge(array, p, q, r):
    left_array = []
    right_array = []

    k = p
    while (k < q):
        left_array.append(array[k])
        k += 1
    while (k < r):
        right_array.append(array[k])
        k += 1

    k = p
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while (i < len(left_array) and j < len(right_array)):
        if (left_array[i] <= right_array[j]):
            array[k] = left_array[i]
            k += 1
            i += 1
        else:
            array[k] = right_array[j]
            k += 1
            j += 1

    while (i < len(left_array)):
        array[k] = left_array[i]
        k += 1
        i += 1

    while (j < len(right_array)):
        array[k] = right_array[j]
        k += 1
        j += 1
    print("Merging", array)

def merge_sort(array, p, r):
    print("Splitting", array)
    if p < r:
        q = floor((p + r) / 2)
        merge_sort(array, p, q)
        merge_sort(array, q + 1, r)
        merge(array, p, q, r)

test3 = [3, 2, 1]
merge_sort(test3, 0, len(test3))
```

**There's a bug somewhere in my code and I can't seem to get it. I think that it has to do with my splicing, but I haven't been able to confirm this.** Here is my output for the test at the bottom:

```
Splitting [3, 2, 1]
Splitting [3, 2, 1]
Splitting [3, 2, 1]
Splitting [3, 2, 1]
Merging [3, 2, 1]
Splitting [3, 2, 1]
Splitting [3, 2, 1]
Splitting [3, 2, 1]
Merging [3, 2, 1]
Merging [2, 1, 3]
```

I took the idea of adding print statements from [here.](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheMergeSort.html)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest adding more print statements or using a proper debugger. For example, you should at least print the left and right arrays before merging them

Comment: did you try to google `python merge sort` and compare those to your implementation? might be worth your time

Comment: `p,q,r` maybe you could give us a clue as to what these are?

Comment: @JamesKPolk p is supposed to be a "pointer" to the first element in the array, r is supposed to be a "pointer" to the last element, and q is the midpoint between the two for the divide step of the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, so basically as described in the link you provided.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I've looked at InteractivePython's implementation of merge sort and, from my understanding, I merge the two subarrays the same way that they do. From what I can tell, what differs is how I construct my left and right subarrays. Whereas they slice the list, I chose to append using a loop. Changing my implementation of this to theirs didn't solve this, however.

Comment: One thing that can be confusing is whether the `p,q,r` bounds should be exclusive or inclusive. If you get that wrong your loops will go either one too long or one too short. You should write some comments that say explicitly what your expecting to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not following the conventions of the text you linked to on whether the bounds are exclusive or inclusive. In the text, they are inclusive, but in your code they are exclusive of the upper bound. As a result, when you have these two lines:

```
merge_sort(array, p, q)
merge_sort(array, q + 1, r)
```

the first sorts `array[p]` through `array[q-1]`, the second sorts `array[q+1]` through `array[r-1]`, and you end up completely skipping `array[q]`.

I think you will find it easier to follow the conventions of the text and make both bounds inclusive. So modify you code, start with

```
test3 = [3, 2, 1]
merge_sort(test3, 0, len(test3) - 1)
```

, and go from there.

You can also clean up your code greatly by using python slice notation. For example:

```
left_array = []
right_array = []

k = p
while (k < q):
    left_array.append(array[k])
    k += 1
while (k < r):
    right_array.append(array[k])
    k += 1
```

can be simplified to

```
left_array = array[p:q]
right_array = array[q:r]
```

although, as I stated, you'll probably want to start using inclusive indices.